# gl_PointCoord has incorrect/uninitialized value

Tags: opengl, libgdx

I am having trouble to get valid values in my fragment-shader's gl_PointCoord variable. I use libgdx, which is a cross-platform java framework that allows to run the same application on the desktop as well on android. The shader works fine with OpenGL ES on android, only the desktop seems to not provide a correctly interpolated value but always zero.

Could this be an issue with libgdx or with the graphics driver?

NVidia Quadro 3000M
Driver 275.33
Win 7 64-bit (Service Pack 1)

libgdx-0.9.6

Comment: Here's a silly question: are you drawing *points*? Do those points have an actual size? In any case, you haven't provided nearly enough information to be able to answer this question.

Comment: yes, i a drawing points and it has an actual size. on android with opengl es, it renders fine; i.e. i am able to texture the sprite because i get meaningful values in gl_PointCoord. On the desktop, it seems to be always zero. I can use the gl_PointCoord as the color-value in the fragment shader and get a black square. That also supports that I am having a valid size: I can see the sprite but it just can't use the gl_PointCoord for texturing because it seems to be uninitialized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fyi: Did not do much research yet, but seems to be a bug in lwjgl or the driver that gl_PointCoord is only available when enabling pointsprite-mode via

```
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
```

This is not available in OpenGL 4.2 or OpenGL ES 2.0, but seems to be required to be explicitly set on the desktop.